# assign only particular column values to a temp table from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am having below query that will return 6 columns and i want only assign particular column (**converted_skus**) results to temporary table and i need to do further processing on that column only ..

I am not sure how can i assign only particular column values to temporary table where as other columns are not needed for further processing

here is my query

```
 SELEct distinct 
 clpAct.pk_cert,CCM.leg_sku_des,CCM.converted_sku_des,CCM.converted_skus,
 esitrans.pk_cert,esitrans.part_id from Clp_Active clpAct 
 inner join transfertable esitrans
 ON clpact.pk_cert = esitrans.pk_cert 
 INNER JOIN pass_conversion CCM
 ON esitrans.part_id = CCM.part_number
 where clpAct.subscription_key = @subKey
```

Would any one please help on this query that would be very grateful to me.
Many thanks in advance

I am using sql server as DB

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need the other columns, then just select your required column only and insert it into the temp table. like this

```
create table #temp
(
converted_skus varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp
(
converted_skus
)
SELEct distinct 
CCM.converted_skus
from Clp_Active clpAct 
 inner join transfertable esitrans
 ON clpact.pk_cert = esitrans.pk_cert 
 INNER JOIN pass_conversion CCM
 ON esitrans.part_id = CCM.part_number
 where clpAct.subscription_key = @subKey
```

now you have only the required column and values in the temp table #temp

Comment: Sorry i need other columns as well not for further processing but to display .. I am trying to get everything into one query

Comment: then, probably insert the columns to the temp table and select only your required column for processing and others can be selected when needed